# estimation of $|f'(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f:D(0,1)\to D(0,1)$ is a analytic map, show that for all $z\in D(0,1)$, $$ |f'(z))|\leq \frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{1-|z|^2}$$

I tried Cauchy's integral formula, but I got stuck. Can someone give me some hint?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us set $\phi_a(z) = \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ for $a\in D(0,1)$. I let you check that $\phi_a$ is an holomorphic bijection from $D(0,1)$ to $D(0,1)$.

Now take a complex $z \in D(0,1)$ and set $w=f(z)$. Consider the new application $$g = \phi_w \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}_z.$$ By construction $g : D(0,1) \to D(0,1)$ is holomorphic and $g(0)=0.$ Hence by Schwartz lemma, we have $$|g'(0)| \leq 1.$$ Can you finish the computation ?